# Easiest way to parse date in String format to GregorianCalendar

Tags: java, time

I have the following date:

```
2011-10-07T08:51:52.006Z
```

Now I want to parse it into a GregorianCalendar. Is there an easier way to do it than using substrings and parsing them to Integers?

And what is the Z in the time string?

I tried to parse it using SimpleDateFormat, but I can´t find a explanation for the T in the date String.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'" )
Date       date = format.parse( "2011-10-07T08:51:52.006Z" );
Calendar   calendar = new GregorianCalendar();

calendar.setTime( date );
```

Comment: The Z (as noted in Gonzalo's answer) is not a constant letter ('Z') but rather an abbreviation for GMT time when using the XXXX ISO-8601 format.

Comment: Calling calendar.setTime( date ) will set the time in millis, but looses the timezone information (the XXXX format as shown by the Z in the example.)

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at `DateTimeFormatter`

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter =
    DateTimeFormat.forPattern("<custom_pattern>").withOffsetParsed();
DateTime dateTime = formatter.parseDateTime("<your_input>");
GregorianCalendar cal = dateTime.toGregorianCalendar();
```

The T in your string acts as a separator between the date and the time and the Z is the time-zone information both as per [ISO-8601 format](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MicrosyntaxDescriptions#datetime-tz).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [SimpleDateFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to parse the String.  Please read the javadoc for the aforementioned class to know what could be the format string.  'Z' indicates the timezone information.